Lyapunov Special Symmetric Case
Consider the Lyapunov equation: $$AX+XA = B$$ and assume that $A$ is symmetric positive definite and $B$ is symmetric.
I am not able to proof that $X=X^{T}$ holds.
Would be grateful if somebody could help out & wish you a nice Sunday.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

The equation can be rewritten as $(I\otimes A+A^T\otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(X)=\operatorname{vec}(B)$. If $A$ is $PD$, then $I\otimes A+A^T\otimes I$ is invertible and hence the solution $X$ exists and is unique. However, as $X$ is a solution, so is $X^T$. Hence the uniqueness of solution implies that $X=X^T$.

Thank you very much. Im new to the topic of matrix equations and wanted to ask why $X^T$ is also a solution in this case? Could you recommend a book on this topics for selfstudy? Best regards

@Lost_In_Math If $AX+XA=B$, then $AX^T+X^TA=(XA+AX)^T=B^T=B$. I haven’t any book at hand. Any engineering or mathematics text that covers Lyapunov equation should have stated the relevant existence and uniqueness theorem in terms of either Kronecker product ($\operatorname{vec}(X)=(I\otimes A+A^T\otimes I)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(B)$) or integral $X=\int_{-\infty}^0e^{tA}Be^{tA}dt$. If I remember correctly, both Wikipedia and Topics in Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson have this covered.
